# Building WebLogic Docker Image in Ubuntu is not working

Tags: linux, docker, ubuntu, weblogic

I have installed in virtual machine the Ubuntu 20.4 operating system. The docker version is 19.03.8.
I cloned the oracle repository with command below:

```
git clone https://github.com/oracle/docker-images.git
```

After that I downloaded the Oracle WebLogic Server 12.2.1.3 - Generic installer.
Than went to the WebLogic docker build directory and place the installer there with the commands below:

```
cd ./docker-images/OracleWebLogic/dockerfiles
mv ./path/to/fmw_12.2.1.3.0_wls_Disk1_1of1.zip ./12.2.1.3
```

In the end I run the build like below:

```
./buildDockerImage.sh -v 12.2.1.3 -g -s
```

In theory everything should be going right, but that is not the case.
I have the problem below:

```
pull access denied for oracle/serverjre, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login'
```

To fix the issue i did the following action:
I logged succefully https://container-registry.oracle.com/ and selected serverjre and accepted the license.

After that I made the following changes in the dockerFile:

```
#FROM oracle/serverjre:8
FROM container-registry.oracle.com/java/serverjre:8
```

Then I logged in the console like below

```
docker login container-registry.oracle.com
username:<SSO USERNAME>
password:<SSO PASSWORD>
```

In the end I run again the build like below, but still it throws the same error.

```
./buildDockerImage.sh -v 12.2.1.3 -g -s
```

Please help with some guidance. Thank you in advance.

P.S This is my first question, I am new here, please don't be hard on me.

Comment: Maybe you can use this WebLogic image set as a base: https://github.com/zappee/docker-images

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the command below:

./buildDockerImage.sh -v 12.2.1.3 -g -s

I see you are running the build with -g option which  creates the images based on generic distribution.
Check this link for more information about the attributes  in the link below:

https://github.com/oracle/docker-images/blob/master/OracleWebLogic/dockerfiles/12.2.1.3/README.md

This means you are using the [DockerFile.generic](https://github.com/oracle/docker-images/blob/master/OracleWebLogic/dockerfiles/12.2.1.3/Dockerfile.generic). You need to do the modification in this file.
You need to do the following replacement:

```
#Line 30
#FROM oracle/serverjre:8 as builder
FROM container-registry.oracle.com/java/serverjre:8 as builder

# Line 69
#FROM oracle/serverjre:8
FROM container-registry.oracle.com/java/serverjre:8
```

Comment: Thank u. I was doing the modification in wrong docker file.